# wrapping images in dynamically created divs in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm having difficulties to wrap my images with dynamically created divs in JS. This is the code which I used:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.appendChild(images[i]);
    mainpictureframe.appendChild(wrapper);

    wrapper.style.background = "red";
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
 
img{ 
 max-width:236px;
}
```

```html
<main id="mainpictureframe"> 
                <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge1" title="16by9-1"/>
                <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge2" title="16by9-1"/>
                <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge3" title="16by9-1"/>
                <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge4" title="16by9-1"/>
                <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge5" title="16by9-1"/>

                <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample1" title="4by3-1"/>
                <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample2" title="4by3-1"/>
                <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample3" title="4by3-1"/>
                <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample4" title="4by3-1"/>
                <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample5" title="4by3-1"/>
</main>
```

It seems like it correctly creates the divs, but only packs every second image into a div.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you need the `wrapper` array? Just create the element and append it (no need to store them in an array). `for(...) { var wrapper = document.createElement("div"); ...}`

Comment: I could add the divs in html, but we have the task to code that you only need to add an image in html and everything still works, so I want to add the divs dynamically in JS for further iteration.

Comment: oops yeah, you are right. The array is not necessary, but even without the array it sadly doesn't change the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a **live** [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). **Live** means that the HTMLCollection reflect the DOM. If some elements get removed, the HTMLCollection get shrunk accordingly.

Since you are looping from the begining of the loop, some elements get left behind.

If the HTMLCollection of images is:

```
[a, b, c, d].
```

then:

```
i = 0 and length = 4
a  b  c  d
^
i
```

then `a` get removed from the collection and `i` get incremented, next:

```
i = 1 and length = 3
b  c  d
   ^
   i
```

`c` get removed and `b` will be skipped because `b` is now at position `0` (because `a` was removed) and `i` is at `1` where `c` is.

.... and so on.

That explains why one image get wrapped and one not...

**Fix:**

Instead of a `for` loop, just make a `while` loop, that checks whether there is still images:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var mainpictureframe = document.getElementById("mainpictureframe");

var len = images.length;
while (len--) {
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    var image = mainpictureframe.removeChild(images[0]);
    wrapper.appendChild(image);
    mainpictureframe.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

**Working fiddle:**

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var mainpictureframe = document.getElementById("mainpictureframe");

var len = images.length;
while (len--) {
  var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  var image = mainpictureframe.removeChild(images[0]);
  wrapper.appendChild(image);
  mainpictureframe.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

img {
  max-width: 236px;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<main id="mainpictureframe">
  <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge1" title="16by9-1" />
  <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge2" title="16by9-1" />
  <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge3" title="16by9-1" />
  <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge4" title="16by9-1" />
  <img src="http://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/61/30/us7TlD.jpg" alt="Stonehenge5" title="16by9-1" />

  <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample1" title="4by3-1" />
  <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample2" title="4by3-1" />
  <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample3" title="4by3-1" />
  <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample4" title="4by3-1" />
  <img src="http://www.freecomputerdesktopwallpaper.com/new_wallpaper/5_4_3_2_1_Happy_New_Year_freecomputerdesktopwallpaper_p.jpg" alt="otherexample5" title="4by3-1" />
</main>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick explanation and answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var wrapper = [];
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
mainpictureframe.appendChild('<div>'+images[i]+'</div>');
}
```

Then you just remove the original images i guess